# update the html page with ajax for every 5 seconds

Tags: ajax, jquery

well i have used an html file like these in iframe

```
<iframe src="sample.html"></iframe>
```

is there a way to refresh these html file for every 5 seconds using ajax so that it does not look as it is refreshing for user rather it should look like its updating

i know a way to do in javascript but it looks so ugly, the refreshing icon keeps on refreshing in the browser.I want to avoid that  is it possible to do these in ajax it should not look like refreshing?Thanks

Comment: Try the below link, if thats not fetching the solution, will get you more..
Thanks [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412302/how-to-refresh-a-iframe-when-the-page-changes-with-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412302/how-to-refresh-a-iframe-when-the-page-changes-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {

            setInterval(function () {
                var x = $('iframe').attr('src');
                $('iframe').attr('src', x);
            }, 5000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your head Tag to refresh HTML page after every 5 seconds

`<script>
     <!--Auto refresh after 5 seconds -->
   setInterval(function(){location.reload(true);},5000);
</script>`

Answer (score -1):

Please run this code in a server. Dont save it in desktop and try..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="5" http-equiv="REFRESH">
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width=100 height=100 frameborder=0    scrolling=no></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work. I have tested it and it was working fine from my end.
Thanks

Comment: sorry but i wanted to update the code you provided will refresh the whole page but it should not look like updating Thanks